Scale factors in Laplacian coordinate transformations
To transform the Laplacian operator $\nabla^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$ to other coordinate systems I learned that you can do it the hard way by just calculating $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$ with the chain rule. I also took an advanced course in general relativity where we learned how to calculate the Laplacian with tensor calculus, metrics, Christoffel symbols, and Einstein summation, which simplified it somewhat, but not necessarily.
I've come across a method that involves scale factors. Take for example polar coordinates, where a length element is given by:$$ds^2=dr^2 + r^2d\theta^2\hspace{1mm},$$
then we can define the scale factors:$$h_r=1\hspace{1mm},\hspace{2cm}h_{\theta}=r\hspace{1mm},$$
by which the Laplacian is:
$$\nabla^2=\frac{1}{h_rh_{\theta}}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{h_{\theta}}{h_r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\frac{h_r}{h_{\theta}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right)\hspace{1mm}\right].\tag{1}$$
This gives the familiar
$$\nabla^2=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}\hspace{1mm}.$$

Likewise for spherical polar with length element $ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+r^2\sin{\theta}^2d\phi^2$, the Laplacian is obtained with:
$$\nabla^2=\frac{1}{h_rh_{\theta}h_{\phi}}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{h_{\theta}h_{\phi}}{h_r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\frac{h_rh_{\phi}}{h_{\theta}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\left(\frac{h_rh_{\theta}}{h_{\phi}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\right)\hspace{1mm}\right].\tag{2}$$

The simple form in $(1)$ and $(2)$ has never come up in anything I've read (I wonder why). Apparentely you can do this with other coordinate systems as well. What is this method and where does it come from?

Surely this is curvilinear coordinates no?

@CheeHan:  yes they are

Then I'm not sure exactly what you're asking?

I'm asking why you can express the Laplacian as in eq. (1) or (2)

The Laplacian can be formally expressed as $\Delta:= \nabla^\alpha\nabla_\alpha$ with $\nabla$ being the covariant derivative. These formulas follow from expanding out that definition.

The formulas you have found above are nothing but the formula shown here, which can be derived from the Voss-Weyl formula

Assume we have coordinates $(x^1,x^2,x^3)$ and let $p(x^1,x^2,x^3)$ be the function taking coordinates to points (represented as position vectors). Then we define the holonomic basis at a point $p(x^1,x^2,x^3)$ as
$$
  e_i(x^1,x^2,x^3) = \frac{\partial p}{\partial x^i}(x^1,x^2,x^3).
$$
Usually we make the coordinate dependence implicit and write just $e_i$.
To any basis there is an associated reciprocal basis $e^i$ uniquely defined by $e^i\cdot e_j = \delta^i_j$.
The direction of e.g. $e_1$ is the direction in which $x^2,x^3$ stay constant, and the direction of e.g. $e^1$ is the direction orthogonal to surfaces of constant $x^1$.
Now recall that $v\cdot\nabla$ is the directional derivative operator; then it ought to be that $e_i\cdot\nabla = \partial/\partial x^i$. It follows immediately that
$$
  \nabla = \sum_ie^i\frac\partial{\partial x^i},\quad \nabla x^i =
e^i.
$$
Thus in general
$$
  \nabla^2 = \sum_{i,j}e^i\cdot\frac\partial{\partial x^i}\left(e^j\frac\partial{\partial x^j}\right) = \sum_{i,j}\left(e^i\cdot\frac{\partial e^j}{\partial x^i}\frac\partial{\partial x^j} + e^i\cdot e^j\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}\right).$$
Now, if $(x^1,x^2,x^3)$ are orthogonal coordinates then $e_1,e_2,e_3$ is an orthogonal basis. Define $h_i = |e_i|$
and $\hat e_i = e_i/h_i$. Then $e^i = \hat e_i/h_i$.
Your formula (2) is obtained by
making this substitution in the formula above for $\nabla^2$ and simplifying.
